# How to draw a diagram for packets scheduling in networks or task scheduling?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pstricks, templates, timing-diagrams

I would like to draw a diagram for packets scheduling in networks similar to the this one:

[image]

The same type of diagram (or very similar) can be used also for tasks scheduling.

Can you please indicate a template for this? Or a resource I could use.

Thanks a lot. The copyright for the image belongs to the [authors from here](http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/54/45/08/PDF/rtns2010_bauer.pdf).

Comment: Do you know about the `pgfgantt` package? See http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfgantt . This package typesets Gantt charts.

Comment: knulp created a task diagram package. Check this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29679/pdflatex-and-pstricks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sketch of an incomplete solution, to optimize

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,fit,calc,positioning}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1,transform shape]

\draw [-latex](-0.5,0) coordinate(dd)-- (0,0) coordinate (O1) -- (17,0)coordinate(ff) node[above]{$t$};
\draw [dashed,thick] (O1) -- (0,1) coordinate(S3) -- (0,3) coordinate(S2) -- (0,5) coordinate(e3) -- ++(0,1)coordinate(ff2);

\foreach \nn in{S3,S2,e3}{
\draw [thick] (dd|-\nn) node[above]{\nn}-- (\nn-|ff);
}

\foreach \xx in{1,2,...,16}{
\draw[dashed] (\xx,0) -- (\xx,0|- ff2);
}

\foreach \xx in{0,4,8,...,16}{
\draw[dashed] (\xx,0.2) -- (\xx,-0.2) node[below]{\xx 0};
}

\begin{scope}[shift={(e3)}]
\node[ above right=0.4cm and 0cm of e3,right,draw, minimum width=4cm,minimum height=0.8cm,fill=white](n3a) {$3=f(e_3)$};
\draw[-latex,thick] (n3a.north west) -- ++(0,0.5)node[right]{$a^{e3}_{3=f(e3)}$};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[shift={(S2)}]
\coordinate(O2) at (2,0);
\node[ above right=0.4cm and 0cm of O2,right,draw, minimum width=4cm,minimum height=0.8cm,fill=white](n4a) {$4=f(s_2)$};
\draw[-latex,thick,green] (n4a.north west) -- ++(0,0.5)node[right,fill=white]{$a^{S2}_{f(S2)}$};
\draw[-latex,thick,blue] ([xshift=2.7cm]n4a.north west) coordinate(bb1)-- ++(0,0.5)node[right,fill=white]{$a^{S2}_{3=f(e3)}$};
\draw[dashed,red] (n3a.south east) -- (bb1);
\node[right=0cm of n4a,right,draw, minimum width=4cm,minimum height=0.8cm,fill=white](n3b) {$3=p(e_3)$};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[shift={(S3)}]
\coordinate(O3) at (0.5,0);
\node[ above right=0.4cm and 0cm of O3,right,draw, minimum width=4cm,minimum height=0.8cm,fill=white](n1) {$1=f(s_2)$};
\node[right=0cm of n1,right,draw, minimum width=4cm,minimum height=0.8cm,fill=white](n5) {$5$};
\node[right=0cm of n5,right,draw, minimum width=4cm,minimum height=0.8cm,fill=white](n4b) {$4=p(S2)$};
\node[right=0cm of n4b,right,draw, minimum width=4cm,minimum height=0.8cm,fill=white](n3c) {$3$};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`rtsched.sty` gives you a high-level syntax for drawing scheduling diagrams in TikZ. Just install the package in your tex distribution or copy the .sty file in your project.

https://github.com/glipari/rtsched

The docfile in the repo has plenty of concrete working examples:
https://github.com/glipari/rtsched/blob/master/rtsched-doc.tex

To see the rendered pictures from the examples, just compile the docfile with your TeX compiler.

Comment: Please add how one can solve the given problem with this package, for example you can add a MWE ...