# Tabular integration by parts

Tags: tables

All I am trying to do is write an integration by parts table in LaTeX. I can't seem to find an .tex code examples anywhere though I have seen pictures of such tables in PDF form (like at http://cazelais.disted.camosun.bc.ca/187/parts.pdf for example). Hopefully someone can let me know real quick.

Comment: There's a lot going on in the link you provided.  It would be helpful if you provided a MWE so we can see what you've managed to put together already.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384). No need to add thanks, simply upvote any good answers you may receive.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146327/how-to-draw-the-diagram-of-calculating-an-integral-by-parts

Answer (score 15):

I assume you are asking about the tabular method of integration by parts, and one way would be to use `tikzmark` to note the location of the points and the after the table draw the arrows between the appropriate points:

[image]

### Note:

- This does require two runs. First one to determine the locations, and the second to do the drawing.
- The `\tikzmark` is from [Adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text/1570#1570).
- You can globally alter the style of the arrows via `Arrow Style`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{Arrow Style/.style={text=black, font=\boldmath}}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{%
    \tikz[overlay, remember picture, baseline] \node (#1) {};%
}

\newcommand*{\XShift}{0.5em}
\newcommand*{\YShift}{0.5ex}

\NewDocumentCommand{\DrawArrow}{s O{} m m m}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \draw[->, thick, Arrow Style, #2] 
                ($(#3.west)+(\XShift,\YShift)$) -- 
                ($(#4.east)+(-\XShift,\YShift)$)
        node [midway,above] {#5};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\[
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{array}{c @{\hspace*{1.0cm}} c}\toprule
       D & I \\\cmidrule{1-2}
      x^2\tikzmark{Left 1} & \tikzmark{Right 1}e^2x \\
      2x \tikzmark{Left 2} & \tikzmark{Right 2}\frac{1}{2} e^{2x} \\      
      2  \tikzmark{Left 3} & \tikzmark{Right 3}\frac{1}{4} e^{2x} \\      
      0  \tikzmark{Left 4} & \tikzmark{Right 4}\frac{1}{8} e^{2x} \\\bottomrule
    \end{array}
\]
%-----------------------------------------
\DrawArrow[draw=red]{Left 1}{Right 2}{$+$}%
\DrawArrow[draw=brown]{Left 2}{Right 3}{$-$}%
\DrawArrow[draw=blue]{Left 3}{Right 4}{$+$}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, that was what I was asking about. Is there a way to add labels above the arrows as well with tikzpicture? Perhaps with a way to specify where along the arrow the label will appear.

Comment: @user25765: Sorry that I missed that earlier. Have updated the answer to include that.

Comment: As I've gotten here via a recent link to this answer, I'd just like to note that tikzmark is now a tikz library and it is better to use the library version.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a start:
There are various approaches to the arrows.  I'll let someone else explain a `tikz` solution.  But you can use `pstricks` and `pst-nodes` to accomplish it.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand{\diff}[1]{\mathrm{d}#1}
\newcommand{\me}{\mathrm{e}}
\begin{document}

\noindent Use \verb=\boxed{...}= to enclose the contents of an equation in a frame.
\[
    \boxed{\int_0^\infty \me^{-x^2}\diff{x}}
\]
Use \verb=\quad= and \verb=\text{...}= to add space and add regular
text in an equation
\[
    u = x \quad \text{ and } \quad \diff v = \cos x \diff x
\]
Use the \verb=align= environment to align math equation upon a given
position in the equation indicated by \verb=&=
\begin{align*}
    \int x \cos x \diff{x} &= x \sin x - \int \sin x \diff x \\
    &= x \sin x + \cos x +C
\end{align*}

\noindent\verb=pstricks= provides \verb=pst-node= to allow you to label and
connect nodes.
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
\[\begin{array}{c@{\hspace*{6em}}c}
    D                   & I                                  \\\hline
    x^2\rnode[br]{A1}{} & \me^{2ex}                          \\
    2x\rnode[br]{B1}{}  & \rnode[l]{B2}{}\frac{1}{2}\me^{2x} \\
    2\rnode[br]{C1}{}   & \rnode[l]{C2}{}\frac{1}{4}\me^{2x}
\end{array}\]
%%
\ncline[nodesep=1em,arrows=->]{A1}{B2}
\lput{:U}{\rput[c]{U}(0,2ex){line label}}
%%
\ncline[nodesep=1em,arrows=->]{B1}{C2}
\lput{:U}{\rput[c]{U}(0,2ex){line label}}


\end{document}
```

[image]

If you would like to go the `pdflatex` route using `pstricks` try the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand{\diff}[1]{\mathrm{d}#1}
\newcommand{\me}{\mathrm{e}}
\begin{document}

\noindent Use \verb=\boxed{...}= to enclose the contents of an equation in a frame.
\[
    \boxed{\int_0^\infty \me^{-x^2}\diff{x}}
\]
Use \verb=\quad= and \verb=\text{...}= to add space and add regular
text in an equation
\[
    u = x \quad \text{ and } \quad \diff v = \cos x \diff x
\]
Use the \verb=align= environment to align math equation upon a given
position in the equation indicated by \verb=&=
\begin{align*}
    \int x \cos x \diff{x} &= x \sin x - \int \sin x \diff x \\
    &= x \sin x + \cos x +C
\end{align*}

\noindent%
\begin{postscript}
\verb=pstricks= provides \verb=pst-node= to allow you to label and
connect nodes.
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
\[\begin{array}{c@{\hspace*{6em}}c}
    D                   & I                                  \\\hline
    x^2\rnode[br]{A1}{} & \me^{2ex}                          \\
    2x\rnode[br]{B1}{}  & \rnode[l]{B2}{}\frac{1}{2}\me^{2x} \\
    2\rnode[br]{C1}{}   & \rnode[l]{C2}{}\frac{1}{4}\me^{2x}
\end{array}\]
%%
\ncline[nodesep=1em,arrows=->]{A1}{B2}
\lput{:U}{\rput[c]{U}(0,2ex){line label}}
%%
\ncline[nodesep=1em,arrows=->]{B1}{C2}
\lput{:U}{\rput[c]{U}(0,2ex){line label}}
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

This is following the instructions found in the answer to [How to use PSTricks in pdfLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8415/22413).  Also, using the environment `\begin{postscript}...\end{postscript}` is per the instructions found at the [pstricks webside](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pdf/pdfoutput#autopstpdf)

Comment: I would have liked this method for the fact that I can readily put labels but I have never been able to get pdflatex to work with PSTricks and I don't yet know how else to get Latex to present a printable form of my work.

Comment: I've had problems using `pdflatex`, but you should be able write `\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}` and the run `pdflatex`.  My problems with `pdflatex` are very localized, but maybe you're running into similar headaches.  I usually go the `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` route since it seems to better respect what I tell `pstricks` to do.

Comment: from the command line try `pdflatex -shell-escape <filehandle>`.  Make sure you've included `\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}` and load `pst-node` through a second call to `\usepackage{pst-node}`

Comment: This [link might be useful](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29679/22413)

Answer (score 3):

With `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{NiceArray}{c @{\hspace*{1.0cm}} c}[create-medium-nodes]
  \toprule
     D & I \\
  \cmidrule{1-2}
    x^2 & e^2x \\
    2x  & \frac{1}{2} e^{2x} \\      
    2   & \frac{1}{4} e^{2x} \\      
    0   & \frac{1}{8} e^{2x} \\
  \bottomrule
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture} [->, name suffix = -medium]
  \draw [red] (2-1) -- node [above] {$+$} (3-2) ; 
  \draw [brown] (3-1) -- node [above] {$-$} (4-2) ; 
  \draw [blue] (4-1) -- node [above] {$+$} (5-2) ; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]